# Java: Why can't I modify variables in class instance

Tags: java, class

Hello I'm currently learning Java and I'm a little confused by the output of one of my programs. The problem I'm running into is the methods I have to modify my object only modify it once. E.g.

```
Class Car{
//initialize car Object
//constructor etc...



 public void accelerate() {
        if(engine == false) {
            System.out.println("The car is not on!");
            return;
        }
        if ((speed + 5) >= maxSpeed) {
            System.out.println("The car can't go any faster!");
            speed = maxSpeed;
            return;
        }
        speed = speed + 5;
    }
```

So this should make it that whenever I call car.accelerate(), I add 5 to the current speed. However when I run it in a loop in main.

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args){

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
    Car mercedes = new Mercedes();
    mercedes.accelerate();
    System.out.println("The Car is going " + mercedes.getSpeed() + " 
mph");}
```

My output is the car is going 5mph, 10 times. What's going on?

Comment: You need to move object creation. `new Car()`, before the `for` loop. If it is inside the loop, you are creating a new object everytime, which explains why the speed is the same.

Comment: I suggest you step through the code in your debugger to see what is going on, but in short when you call `new Car()` it creates a new Car object each time, so you are starting from scratch repeatedly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are initializing new object (new Mercedes()) inside loop, each time you run the loop you are getting the above mentioned output.

If you want the value to get incremented initialize variable out side the loop

```
 Car mercedes = new Mercedes();
 for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
 {
    mercedes.accelerate();
    System.out.println("The Car is going " + mercedes.getSpeed() + " 
mph");
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Each time in the loop you are creating a new instance of the car: `Car mercedes = new Mercedes();`. So everytime you start with a new car at 0 mph.
Move the object creation before the for loop, then it should work correctly.